# Java PrintWriter Not sending Byte Array

Tags: java, sockets

A byte array of unknown size is needed to be sent over a socket. When i try to write the byte array to printwriter like

```
        writeServer = new PrintWriter(socketconnection.getOutputStream());
        writeServer.flush();
        writeServer.println("Hello World");
        writeServer.println(byteArray.toString());
```

It is received at the server but is only a string of 5-6 characters always starting from [B@..... But when i send it through the output stream like

```
        writeServer.println("Hello World");
        socketconnection.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);
```

It is received at the server correctly. But the issue is in the second option the "Hello World" String does not go through to the server. I want both of things delivered to the server.

How should i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to mix binary and text which is bound to be confusing. I suggest you use one or the other.

```
// as text
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socketconnection.getOutputStream());
pw.println("Hello World");
pw.println(new String(byteArray, charSet);
pw.flush();
```

or

```
// as binary
BufferedOutputStream out = socketconnection.getOutputStream();
out.write("Hello World\n".getBytes(charSet));
out.write(byteArray);
out.write(`\n`);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

`byteArray.toString()` will return you human readable form of `byteArray`. Even though for Arrays it is never human readable.

If you want to transfer `byteArray` as `String` then you should use

```
String str = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());//Specify different charset value if required.
```